# Fundamental thermodynamic relation: derivation of "non-natural" variables

Tags: thermodynamics, maxwell-relations

Maybe this could be case where a question, other than an answer, could be wrong, but whatever...

Let's start with the fundamental thermodynamic relation in differential form for a hydrostatic system, $dE=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$.

Via the [Euler's homogeneous functions theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) we could write too $E=TS-PV+\mu N$.

So what could stop us from writing, i.e., $V$ as $V=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial P}$? Why we have to switch to enthalpy?

Comment: have you forgot that the other variables $T, S, \mu, N, etc.$ may also depend on $p$?

Comment: Also, how much time in the  calculations of TD processes, especially as you get further into it,  does the enthalpy concept save us? Schroeder in "Thermal Physics" covers this pretty well, imo

Comment: Please @hyportnex could you elaborate more, or offer a reference? From the textbooks I'm reading I know just that $S=S(E,V,N)$ or $T=T(E,V,N)$...

Comment: So @JohnKennedy there's just an experimental motivation?

Comment: I don't know how far you have got into TD and SM, but these concepts, enthalpy , Helmholtz , Gibbs free energy etc are all **in actual  practice, and even theoretically** as fundamental as the fundamental variables you have listed. If you look through the TOC of any textbook you will see what I mean. I hope I am addressing your question correctly, sorry if this is old stuff to you.

Comment: Unfortunately the textbook I'm using has a well developed SM part, but a very succinct TD one - so I'm encountering various problems. I've understood, also by the @hyportnex comment, that there are some crossed dependencies...i.e., in what sense $N$ depends on $p$?

Comment: First **law** of thermodynamics asserts the relationship: $dE=TdS=PdV+\mu dN$. It's an axiom. Beginning from this point no amount of mathematical manipulation can get you the result $V=-\partial E/\partial p$.

Comment: Even in an indirect way, I think yours @Deep was the appropriate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because $T,p$ and $\mu$ are not extensive variables.

The natural variables for the internal energy $U$, $(S,N,V)$, are extensive, i.e. they are additive for subsystems: if I put together two systems of entropy $S_1$ and $S_2$, the total entropy is $S_1+S_2$. The same is valid for $N$ and $V$, but it is *not* valid for $T,P$ and $\mu$.

So it is true that $U$ is homogeneous of degree $1$ in $S,N$ and $V$:

$$U(\lambda S, \lambda N, \lambda V) = \lambda U(S,N,V)$$

and therefore we can use Euler's theorem to write*

$$U = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}S+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}V +  \frac{\partial U}{\partial N}N = TS-pV+\mu N$$

but $U$ is *not* homogeneous in $T,p$ and $\mu$.
Therefore we *cannot* write

$$U = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}T+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial p}p +  \frac{\partial U}{\partial \mu}\mu$$

---

$^*$ More details [here](https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/EulerGibbsDuhem.html).

Comment: I think my mistake stemmed from a geometric perspective, i.e. trying to think of the thermodynamic space as a 7-dimensional Euclidean one.